# Constrained maximization of function and not-successful attempts in Python3

Tags: python, matlab, python-3.x, scipy, numerical-methods

Firstly, I will present the problem.
[image: LaTex description of problem]

## My attempt

I tried to solve this problem with *scipy.optimize* package. I had to pass the initial vector (initial guess). And value, which was given by algorithm was dependent on this initial guess. So I tried to take random initial guesses and tried to find maximal values among more and more initial guesses

```python
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def J(data):
    l = len(data)
    if (l%2==0 | l<2):
        raise Exception('Wrong length or arguments!')

    phi = data[0:l//2]
    p = data[l//2:l-1]
    theta = data[l-1]
     
    phi = np.array(phi)    
    p = np.array(p)
    
    w = (1 + np.cos(phi)*np.cos(theta))*p
    lam = (1+np.cos(phi-theta))/(2*(1+np.cos(phi)*np.cos(theta)))
    
    return -(1 - sum(w * ((-lam*np.log2(lam)) - (1-lam)*np.log2(1-lam))))

def probability_constraint(x):
    return sum(x[len(x)//2:len(x)-1])-1

def lambda_w_constraint(data):
    l = len(data)
    phi = data[0:l//2]
    p = data[l//2:-1]
    theta = data[l-1]
    
    phi = np.array(phi)    
    p = np.array(p)
        
    w = (1 + np.cos(phi)*np.cos(theta))*p
    lam = (1+np.cos(phi-theta))/(2*(1+np.cos(phi)*np.cos(theta)))    
    return sum(w*lam)-1/2

def lambda_greater_than_zero(data):
    l = len(data)
    phi = data[0:l//2]
    p = data[l//2:-1]
    theta = data[l-1]
        
    lam = (1+np.cos(phi-theta))/(2*(1+np.cos(phi)*np.cos(theta)))    
    return lam

def probability_positive(x):
    return x

cons = ({'type': 'ineq',
'fun' : lambda x: lambda_greater_than_zero(x)},
        {'type': 'eq',
'fun' : lambda x: probability_constraint(x)},
        {'type': 'eq',
'fun' : lambda x: lambda_w_constraint(x)},
        {'type':'ineq', 
'fun' : lambda x: probability_positive(x)}

)

def maximize(numiter):
    maxJ = -1000
    maxx = []

    for i in range(0, numiter):
        x0 = np.random.rand(5)*10
        res = minimize(J, x0, constraints=cons)
        r = J(res.x)
        if (r>maxJ):
            maxJ = r
            maxx = res.x
        
    return maxJ, maxx

maximize(10)

maximize(100)
```

I know, that this method is very naive and incorrect.

So my question is: do you know how to solve this problem? It can be in python3, but other languages (Matlab?) are also good for me.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, since `phi`, `p`, `n`, are not changing, isn't `theta` the only variable that's changing, and its change affects the min/max outcome of the function `f` ?

Comment: Concerning MATLAB, you can have a look at [`fmincon`](https://mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html)

Comment: Miket25, phi and p may change, n is given (but if it will be easier, n may be just 2).